# VBA loop through Pivot fields and change number format of specific cells based on 1 criteria

Tags: excel, vba, format, pivot-table

I am trying to change the (blank) cells in a handful of pivot tables on the activesheet. What I thought was a simple code is giving me more problems than I thought.

```
Sub HideBlank()
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim P_i As PivotField

For Each pvt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
Debug.Print pvt.Name

    For Each P_i In pvt.PivotFields
        If P_i.Value = "(blank)" Then
            P_i.NumberFormat = ";;;"
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the PivotFields collection and then loop though the PivotItems collection. The PivotField is like a column of the table, and the PivotItem is the individual cell. PivotFields don't have values, they have a collection of PivotItems and each PivotItem has a value.

Other than that, there is a second problem. PivotItems are not explicitly tied to cells of a pivot table. For example, if they are hidden by use of a filter, then they have no associated cell on the worksheet despite being data currently tied to the PivotField. So you cannot do `PivotItem.NumberFormat` because they are not a `Range`. Each pivot item can give you its `PivotItem.LabelRange` which will tell you where it is located on the worksheet *if it is* currently located on the worksheet. And you could do `PivotItem.LabelRange.NumberFormat`, but `LabelRange` doesn't always exist.

If the PivotItem is hidden `PivotItem.LabelRange` gives an error instead of a `Range`. So to test if the `PivotItem` currently has a `Range`, you need to skip errors, ask for `LabelRange` and then test if the result is a valid `Range`.

After getting a valid range, you can set `.NumberFormat` as desired.

```vb
Sub HideBlank()
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim P_f As PivotField
    Dim P_i As PivotItem
    Dim ItemRange As Range
    
    For Each pvt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    Debug.Print pvt.Name
        For Each P_f In pvt.PivotFields
            For Each P_i In P_f.PivotItems
                If P_i.Visible And P_i.Value = "(blank)" Then
                    Set ItemRange = Nothing
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set ItemRange = P_i.LabelRange
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not ItemRange Is Nothing Then
                        ItemRange.NumberFormat = ";;;"
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Instructive & helpful; you've packed more information into four small paragraphs than is often found in voluminous textbooks +:) @Toddleson